# Git merge doesn't update locally

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a git issue with merging master into my branch.

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git pull

git checkout my-branch
git merge master
```

Outputs: `Already up to date.`

However, locally I can see changes between the two branches.

When I try to push from my-branch, I get pre-push errors that are already fixed in master and should be updated with a merge.

my-branch git log:

```
commit 861151c88109dd6910ecd2ba50b2f8791b735ba4 (HEAD -> my-branch)
Author: suqui <>
Date:   Thu Oct 20 10:48:30 2022 +0200

    remove description from autocomplete

commit 6e90e6d6224fed52e3ae1c70f4bfe31b695fa011
Author: suqui <>
Date:   Thu Oct 20 10:47:08 2022 +0200

    description check for list

commit d6dc18a5bddce40e31f57ca3d4a7784e67e8661d (origin/my-branch)
Merge: 87004fe5 c7bd3be1
Author: suqui <>
Date:   Wed Oct 19 16:29:26 2022 +0200

    Merge branch 'master' into LB-308

commit c7bd3be1c9aac4ef439149c8b929f4a993f1f9ca (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master, other-branch)
Author: Backstage <>
Date:   Wed Oct 19 16:14:48 2022 +0200

    [ci skip] Automatically added catalog-info.yaml
```

Master git log:

```
commit c7bd3be1c9aac4ef439149c8b929f4a993f1f9ca (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, other-branch)
Author: Backstage <>
Date:   Wed Oct 19 16:14:48 2022 +0200

    [ci skip] Automatically added catalog-info.yaml
```

output from `git log --graph --oneline master my-branch`:

```
* 861151c8 (HEAD -> my-branch) remove description from autocomplete
* 6e90e6d6 description check for list
*   d6dc18a5 (origin/my-branch) Merge branch 'master' into LB-308
|\  
| * c7bd3be1 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master, other-branch) [ci skip] Automatically added catalog-info.yaml
```

Comment: Show us the result of `git log`
Looks like master is behind 'my-branch'

Comment: yeah.... `git log --graph --oneline master my-branch`.

Comment: updated. so do I need to stash changes first and then merge master? Even if the master merge affects completely different files?

Comment: There are no changes that are not in your branch. Your branch (`my-branch`) already fully contains master. Any changes you see are in the commits only reachable from your branch ref (861151c8 and 6e90e6d6; or any of the first parents of d6dc18a5).

Comment: Yes but in my files I can see the changes.
Master contains additional info that are not merged into my branch, hence the question

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the project and re-cloning it. The problem then disappeared.